# Trying to set a copy to clipboard link in blogger blog1 widget

Tags: clipboard, blogger

Im trying to configure a copy link to clipboard in my home page in blogger for each different article `(data:post.url)`, at the end of other links to social webs, but I've not luck with the sintaxis.
This is what I would like to obtain:

```
<a href='javascript:getlink("https://www.venalacocina.com");'>
```

And this is the code what I'm trying to write to obtain those result

```
<a class='copi' expr:href='&quot;javascript:getlink(\&quot;&quot;+ data:post.url + &quot;\&quot;);' id='btnCopiar'>
```

I'm lost with the appropriate use of &quot; and " ¿how many and where should I use them to set the correct code?
¿Would someone give me the correct code correctly written?
thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did it; it was just a question of time.

I just changed and simplified the expression calling directly `getlink()` function and this is the result working perfectly for me:

```
<a class='copi' expr:onclick='&quot;getlink(&apos;&quot;+ data:post.url + &quot;&apos;);&quot;' id='btnCopiar'>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @JeremyCaney for the corrections to the format of my text. I like a lot to learn from demanding people to improve my English and coding.